# JDBC driver for SQL Server 7.0?

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-7

I need to retrieve datas from the SQL Server 7.0 through java.

I have tried the following drivers

- msbase.jar
- mssqlserver.jar
- msutil.jar
- sqljdbc.jar
- sqljdbc4.jar

These jars works fine for the SQL Server versions 2000 and above, but for the version 7.0 its displaying error like **The TDS prelogin response is incomplete. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later.**

What are the drivers I should use to retrieve datas from the Sql Server 7.0 through java?

Comment: Came across this Googling "The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later." - in my case the issue was that I needed a newer version of SQL Server Management Studio to connect to SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **jtds** driver should work fine.

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

I have used it for MSSQL 2000, but the website claims it works for 7.0 as well.

Comment: One word of caution: the jtds developers reverse-engineered the TDS protocol, and their implementation is lacking in places.  If it works for you, great, but it hasn't worked for me in the past.  In my case (with Sybase), the vendor-supplied jdbc driver was much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Version 7.0 you say?

That brings memories!

Back in the day we used JDBC driver from the company currently named DataDirect to connect to SQL Server 7.0.

Back in the day we had to pay for the JDBC drivers and we were lucky if it was available for the platform we needed.